# Comparing images from 2 different files in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to count the results of an image classification function, but I keep getting an error of not being able to find a certain file

```
f=dir('C:\Users\bla\Documents\MATLAB\Test');
countco = 0;
countfo = 0;
counthi = 0;
countic = 0;
files={f.name};
for k=3:86
  fullFileName = fullfile(files{k});
im = imread(fullFileName);
sub = image_classificationhsv(im);
if (result==Coast)
    countcoa = countcoa + 1; 
end
if (result==Forest)
    countcoa = countfo + 1; 
end
if (result==Highway)
    countcoa = countcoa + 1; 
end
if (result==City)
    countcoa = countcoa + 1; 
end
end
```

the function image_classification hsv code

```
function [class] = image_classificationhsv(image1)
f=dir('C:\Users\bla\Documents\MATLAB\Train');
files={f.name};
for k=1:numel(files)
fullFileName = fullfile(files{k});
cellArrayOfImages{k}=imread(fullFileName);
end
```

I keep getting an error :

```
 Error using ==> imread at 372
 File "coast_arnat59.jpg" does not exist.

 Error in ==> image_classificationhsv at 7
    cellArrayOfImages{k}=imread(fullFileName);
```

Comment: how can i take the location ?

Comment: i changed the path to C:\Users\bla\Documents\MATLAB\Test\\*.jpg and C:\Users\bla\Documents\MATLAB\Train\\*.jpg and i am still getting the same error

Comment: the line `fullFileName = fullfile(files{k});` doesn't do what you expect. Try this: `fullFileName = fullfile('C:\Users\etc\Train',files{k});`

Answer (score 0):

The path needs to be added when you read the files. The easiest way is to just concatenate strings with `[]`.

```
p = 'C:\Users\bla\Documents\MATLAB\Test\'
f = dir([p,'*.jpg']); % jpg files in directory
```

Then:

```
fname = [p, files{k}]; % path + file name
yourcellarray{k} = imread(fname);
```